# When should a question that has been closed as 'too broad' be re-opened?

Tags: discussion

I got audited and failed and now I'm mad because I think I was right!

But seriously, if a riddle has attracted 6 answers that explain all the lines in the riddle, how is that riddle not 'too broad'?

Am I misunderstanding 'too broad' in this context?

I noticed that when reviewing re-open votes we are not shown the answers that have been suggested. As I'm not very good at solving riddles I decided to have a look at the question to see if it gave rise to lots of possible solutions. I supposed this could be considered 'cheating' in the context of the review process, I thought it was the easiest way to see if the riddle really was 'too broad'.

Given that all of the answers seemed to fit the riddle (the questioner had commented on some of the 'wrong' answers saying that they seem to fit) and the definition in the help centre of 'too board' is...

if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has **many valid answers**, it's probably too broad for our format

...where is the boundary between okay and 'too broad'?

So when do you think a question that has been closed as 'too broad' should be re-opened?

Comment: The first question on meta PSE complaining about review audits ;)

Comment: I'm assuming [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/10702) was the audit. In general, it's not considered cheating if you visit the link. Audits are here to make sure you are paying attention and not robo-reviewing. If you actually spend the time to move your mouse to the link button, click it, scroll down, and read everything, you are probably okay and should pass the audit.

Comment: (Cont.) I agree with you that the question is too broad. Sometimes, the system picks stupid audits, and there's really nothing we can do except vote to close it, which would prevent it from showing up as an audit again. If you are not robo-reviewing (which I hope you are not doing), you should not fail enough audits to get a review ban. Failing a couple now and then is normal.

Comment: Thanks. That was the question I was given to review. Good to know that I'm not doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I voted to close [the question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15977/4551). I think it's too broad, and while it's too late for your audit, we can close it now and it won't appear in future audits.

Having read the riddle, hints, and accepted answer, I would not know it to be the right answer if not for the green checkmark. And some of the competing answers seem about as plausible. I'm not a fan of hints invalidating answers after the fact, but here I think even having the hints isn't enough.